# Creating random number on fractional part between two numbers

Tags: javascript

I am working on the following code. How can I create random number between **150**.***570*** and **150**.***720***?

As you can see the  integer-part (150) is always fixed  and I just need to get random on fractional-part (between .570 to .720) only.

```js
var gapLeft = Math.floor(Math.random() *  150.720) +  150.570  ;
console.log(gapLeft);
```

Comment: To get a random number between 0.57 and 0.72: `0.57 + Math.random() * (0.72 - 0.57)`. You could do:  `150.57 + Math.random() * (0.72 - 0.57)`

Comment: Great, Thanks a lots  this is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution for this,

```
console.log(150.57+Math.random()*(0.72-0.57));
```